# Exploring Data loaded to an internal stage in snowflake

Tags: sql, csv, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, parquet, stage

Data was loaded to an internal stage called MY_CH07_STAGE in snowflake. To explore the data we have the query below.

What does t mean and what does t.$1, t.$2,t.$3,t.$4,t.$5 and t.$6 mean?

```
select t.$1, t.$2,t.$3,t.$4,t.$5,t.$6
from @MY_CH07_STAGE (file_format => 'my_stage_file_format') t;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`t` is the alias to the "table" in this case the stage, and the format of the files found in there.

The `.$1` is the first column of values.

For example from the [Parquet data loading example](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/script-data-load-transform-parquet#step-4-copy-data-into-the-target-table)

```
copy into cities
 from (select $1:continent::varchar,
              $1:country:name::varchar,
              $1:country:city::variant
      from @sf_tut_stage/cities.parquet);
```

> Note the following:
>
> `$1` in the SELECT query refers to the single column where the Paraquet data is stored.

thus the `$2` to `$6` are the 2nd to 6th columns in the files column format.

Comment: Great, thank you Simeon for your answer.